# Twitter search API results not reflective of advanced search function

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-search

I am interested in checking for tweets within a 300mi radius of Detroit with the query `tigers`. Here is the link I have been using for my python program:

```
DetroitTigersURL='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=tigers&amp;rpp=100&amp;lang=en&amp;geocode=42.42,83.02,300mi&amp;'
```

...which only returns about 15 tweets, 13 of which are from a guy in Kazakhstan.

and here's that same search using Twitter's built in advanced search: 
https://twitter.com/search?q=%22tigers%22%20near%3A%22Detroit%22%20within%3A300mi&src=typd

...with plenty of fresh tweets ripe for the picking. A little help please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for one of these kinds of answers, but it appears to be an issue with the `geocode` API parameter. See the following links for somewhat related discussions:

- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4003
- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4004
- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/2147
- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3360

Comment: thanks for the contribution. I've yet to find a good workaround yet, so if you come up with anything please let me know.

Comment: @SamMerrick Will do - I know how frustrating it can be when the solution is totally out of your hands.